# Dynamically created UIBarButtonItem doesn't trigger on tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uitoolbar

I've got a UIPickerView that has a UIToolbar attached to it on the parent view's load with this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.itemSortPicker.hidden = false;

    pickerData = @[@"Name",@"Item Level",@"Crafting Level",@"Profit",@"Profit Percentage",@"Sell Price",@"Buy Price",@"Supply",@"Demand",@"Rarity"];

    self.itemSortPicker.dataSource = self;
    self.itemSortPicker.delegate = self;


    UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

    pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];

    [pickerToolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -pickerToolbar.bounds.size.height, 320, 44)];

    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(pickerCancel)];
    [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDone)];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];

    [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

    CGRect pickerRect = self.itemSortPicker.bounds;
    self.itemSortPicker.bounds = pickerRect;
    self.itemSortPicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 216);

    [self.itemSortPicker addSubview:pickerToolbar];

}
```

Now the problem is, when I tap on either the 'done' or 'cancel' buttons, the associated method doesn't trigger. The method doesn't take any parameters and just does an NSLog action. The PickerView isn't taking focus from the bar because when I tap and drag on the buttons, the PickerView doesn't change.

Comment: And just to double check... Your picker view has user interaction enabled?

Comment: The picker itself can be interacted with. I can drag it about and everything.

Comment: Are the interfaces inplace in the .h file? "UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate"? Also don't forget to add [pickerView setDataSource: self];
[pickerView setDelegate: self];

Comment: Oh, is me using `self.itemSortPicker.dataSource = self;` the same as `[pickerView setDataSource: self];`?

Comment: Oh, never mind, I see the problem... I'll post an answer. One sec...

Comment: @JamEngulfer221 Yes it is the same.

Comment: The problem is that your toolbar is outside of the picker's frame. I've posted the explanation in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `UIToolbar` isn't entirely inside the frame of the `UIPickerView`.  As your code is written, although `UIToolbar` is a subview of `UIPickerView`, the toolbar is `-pickerToolbar.bounds.size.height` above the `UIPickerView`:

```
[pickerToolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -pickerToolbar.bounds.size.height, 320, 44)];
```

so you're unable to interact with its buttons because it's hanging off the edge of its superview's frame. For example, if you changed the pickerToolbar frame like so:

```
[pickerToolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
```

you should be able to interact with it.

If you need this specific placement `-pickerToolbar.bounds.size.height` above the `UIPickerView` though, I suggest not adding it as a subview to `UIPickerView` and placing it appropriately as a subview to `UIPickerView`'s superview instead. In general, if you need to interact with a subview it needs to be entirely within its superview's frame.

Edit: In this case, if you're going to instead add the toolbar to the superview, like so:

```
[self.view addSubview:pickerToolbar];
```

I suggest trying out this frame to maintain your original placement:

```
[pickerToolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(self.itemSortPicker.frame.origin.x, self.itemSortPicker.frame.origin.y - pickerToolbar.bounds.size.height, 320, 44)];
```

(To calculate this new frame, I've added the `UIPicker`'s x and y origin values to the frame's x and y to adjust for the change in the view's coordinate system.)

Comment: Yeah, if I use the correction you made, the toolbar is just placed over the top of the UIPickerView. From that, if I try and use the bar, it just interacts with the picker

Comment: @JamEngulfer221 That may be the case, so I removed that example (not a correction, but example). My point is that you can't interact with the toolbar when it's outside of its superview (i.e. -pickerToolbar.bounds.size.height), so the best solution would be to do what I described in the last paragraph and not put the toolbar within the picker if you can't contain it within the picker's frame.

Comment: I added the toolbar to what I think is the parent view: `[self.view addSubview:pickerToolbar];`, but now the toolbar itself is missing.

Comment: @JamEngulfer221 If you kept the frame as `CGRectMake(0, -pickerToolbar.bounds.size.height, 320, 44)` then that's happening because your toolbar is again `-pickerToolbar.bounds.size.height` above your view. You need to adjust the frame so it's within the frame.

Comment: @JamEngulfer221 I've edited my answer to include the new frame calculation.

Comment: Hmm, weird... I might have messed some stuff up in the storyboard, but it works now. I didn't end up needing to subtract the height of the toolbar from the picker's x coordinate.

Comment: @JamEngulfer221 Oh, gotcha...then I'll add back in the example I had earlier with CGRect(0,0,...) for future answer seekers. Glad to hear it works!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of wether the problem is because of the button or the toolbar itself nor the pickerview but a better way of doing this is to do it all programmatically and you have to remove the pickerview from the view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    pickerData = @[@"Name",@"Item Level",@"Crafting Level",@"Profit",@"Profit Percentage",@"Sell Price",@"Buy Price",@"Supply",@"Demand",@"Rarity"];

    UIPickerView *itemSortPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 162)];
    itemSortPicker.dataSource = self;
    itemSortPicker.delegate = self;
    itemSortPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(pickerCancel)];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDone)];

    UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [pickerToolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
    [toolBar setItems:@[cancelBtn,flexSpace,doneBtn]];

    BlaBlaTextField.delegate = self;
    BlaBlaTextField.inputView = itemSortPicker;
    BlaBlaTextField.inputAccessoryView = pickerToolbar;
}
```

And not to forget your ***pickerCancel*** and ***pickerDone*** functions, and of course the delegate methods of your itemSortPicker.

I hope that solves your problem.